# #jxbrowser zoom-in and zoom-out

Tags: zooming, jxbrowser

In jxbrowser application, I am trying to zoom in or out to change the application scale with CTRL + wheel up/ down.
Is there any option to allow CTRL + wheel up or down in order to change the application scale?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding this part of code:

```
private static int mainBrowser = 1;
 frame.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            if (e.isControlDown()) {
                if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
                    mainBrowser.setZoomLevel(zoomValue += 1);

                } else {
                    mainBrowser.setZoomLevel(zoomValue -= 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is a smart solution for JxBrowser 6 in Swing. For JxBrowser 7, use @Maaatzi's answer that will work in all UI toolkits.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this code in JxBrowser 7.31:

```
browser.set(MoveMouseWheelCallback.class, new MoveMouseWheelCallback() {
  @Override
  public Response on(Params arg0) {
    MouseWheel mw = arg0.event();

    /* pressing control + using mouse wheel */
    if (mw.keyModifiers().isControlDown() == true) {
      Zoom z = browser.zoom();
      double zl = browser.zoom().level().value();

      if (mw.deltaY() > 0 && (zl + 0.1) <= ZoomLevel.P_500.value())
        z.level(ZoomLevel.of(zl + 0.1)); /* zoom in */
      else if (mw.deltaY() < 0 && (zl - 0.1) >= ZoomLevel.P_25.value())
        z.level(ZoomLevel.of(zl - 0.1)); /* zoom out */

      return Response.suppress();
    }

    return Response.proceed();
  }

});
```